# node js http get returning error

Tags: node.js, http, express

Here i am trying to do http get. But its returning following error.Please any one guide me to go with correct solution.

```
var https = require('http');
        var options = {
              host: 'lifecycle-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com',
              path: 'resource/validation?validationField=suffix',         //This is the only line that is new. `headers` is an object with the headers to request
              headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        /*'charset':'UTF-8'*/
            },
              method: 'GET'
    };
    callback = function(resp) {         
        console.log(resp);
    }   

    var req = https.request(options, callback);
    //req.write("grant_type=password&username=baraffinity&password=lalol1&oauth_consumer_key=0mlvq6t6053e924864d4pw229h32b90a");
    req.end();
```

and the error is

```
        readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null },
 readable: true,
 domain: null,
 _events:
  { end: [Object],
    finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
    _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
    free: [Function],
    close: [Object],
    agentRemove: [Function],
    drain: [Function: ondrain],
    error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
    connect: undefined },
 _maxListeners: 10,
 _writableState:
  { highWaterMark: 16384,
    objectMode: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    decodeStrings: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    buffer: [] },
 writable: true,
 allowHalfOpen: false,
 onend: [Function: socketOnEnd],
 destroyed: false,
 errorEmitted: false,
 bytesRead: 508,
 _bytesDispatched: 125,
 _pendingData: null,
 _pendingEncoding: '',
 parser:
  { _headers: [],
    _url: '',
    onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
    onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
    onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
    onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
    socket: [Circular],
    incoming: [Circular],
    maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
    onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient] },
 _httpMessage:
  { domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _maxListeners: 10,
    output: [],
    outputEncodings: [],
    writable: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _hangupClose: false,
    socket: [Circular],
    connection: [Circular],
    agent: [Object],
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    path: 'resource/validation?validationField=suffix',
    _headers: [Object],
    _headerNames: [Object],
    _header: 'GET resource/validation?validationField=suffix HTTP/1.1\r\nHo
t: lifecycle-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
    _headerSent: true,
    parser: [Object],
    res: [Circular] },
 ondata: [Function: socketOnData] },


httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers:
   { date: 'Thu, 31 Jul 2014 09:39:50 GMT',
     server: 'Apache/2.2.22 (Amazon)',
     'content-length': '326',
     connection: 'close',
     'content-type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' },
  trailers: {},
  _pendings: [],
  _pendingIndex: 0,
  url: '',
  method: null,
  statusCode: 400,
  client:
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle:
      { fd: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState:
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function],
        close: [Object],
        agentRemove: [Function],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
        connect: undefined },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState:
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     onend: [Function: socketOnEnd],
     destroyed: false,
     errorEmitted: false,
     bytesRead: 508,
     _bytesDispatched: 125,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     parser:
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient] },
     _httpMessage:
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'resource/validation?validationField=suffix',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _header: 'GET resource/validation?validationField=suffix HTTP/1.1\r\nHo
t: lifecycle-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
        _headerSent: true,
        parser: [Object],
        res: [Circular] },
     ondata: [Function: socketOnData] },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  upgrade: false,
  req:
   { domain: null,
     _events: { response: undefined, socket: undefined },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: false,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _hangupClose: false,
     socket:
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        onend: [Function: socketOnEnd],
        destroyed: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bytesRead: 508,
        _bytesDispatched: 125,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        parser: [Object],
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        ondata: [Function: socketOnData] },
     connection:
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        onend: [Function: socketOnEnd],
        destroyed: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bytesRead: 508,
        _bytesDispatched: 125,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        parser: [Object],
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        ondata: [Function: socketOnData] },
     agent:
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        options: {},
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        maxSockets: 5,
        createConnection: [Function] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     method: 'GET',
     path: 'resource/validation?validationField=suffix',
     _headers: { host: 'lifecycle-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com' },
     _headerNames: { host: 'Host' },
```

Comment: its not an error, this is your response object @chan, what exactly is the error you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error. You're printing the response object to console.

Change your callback to

`callback = function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
}`

Documentation: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback